# How to recursively query the nested documents of mogodb？

Tags: mongodb, graphlookup

```
  {
    "id": "1505036191456227329",
    "materialList": [
        {
            "id": "1505035441229459457",
            "model": "",
            "parentId": "0",
        
        },
          {
            "id": "1505035441229459458",
            "model": "",
            "parentId": "1505035441229459457",
        
        }, {
            "id": "1505035441229459459",
            "model": "",
            "parentId": "1505035441229459457",
        
        },{
            "id": "1505035441229459460",
            "model": "",
            "parentId": "1505035441229459459",
        
        }
    ]

}
```

this is my data,I want to find all sub data IDS with ID 1505035441229459457 under the materiallist。

The result of the query is 1505035441229459458,1505035441229459459,1505035441229459460

Comment: You can only query in flat document by using [graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use $elemMatch for this.

> Ex -> db.collection.find( { materialList: { $elemMatch: {id:
> 1505035441229459457 } } })

Comment: I need to recursively query all sub data